# Exception handling in promises

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, promise

Sometimes constructing a promise there may be an exceptional condition such as database refused the connection or invalid host name parameter for database, for example:

In db.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports.connect = (options) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const connection = mysql.createConnection(getDBConfig());
      connection.connect();
      resolve(connection);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error('Error connecting database');
    }
  });
};

function getDBConfig() {
  const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
  const config = {
    debug: !isProd,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    database: 'xxx'
  };

  if (isProd) {
    return Object.assign({
      password: 'root'
    }, config);
  } else {
    return Object.assign({
      password: 'xxx'
    }, config);
  }
}
```

In app.js

```
'use strict';

const database = require('./db');
const server = require('./server');

// log unhandled execpetions
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.error('Unhandled Exception', err.message);
});

process.on('uncaughtRejection', (err, promise) => {
  console.error('Unhandled Rejection', err);
});

database.connect({
})
.then((connection) => {
  console.log('Connected to database');
});
```

In the above case there is no instance of mysql running, the output that I get in the console is:

```
Connected to database
Unhandled Exception connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

Which is not as expected, I need to know what is the recommended approach and what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not handling errors in the `connect` call. See lines with `***` comments:

```
module.exports.connect = (options) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const connection = mysql.createConnection(getDBConfig());
      connection.connect(err => {                         // ***
        if (err) {                                        // ***
          reject(new Error('Error connecting database')); // ***
        } else {                                          // ***
          resolve(connection);                            // ***
        }                                                 // ***
      });                                                 // ***
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error('Error connecting database');
    }
  });
};
```

The `try`/`catch` will catch synchronous errors that occur, but `connect` reports success/failure via callback. More in the [npm mysql documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql).

And, of course, then *handle* the rejection with a `catch` handler at point of use, as [trincot pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46139162/157247).

Comment: @codeyogi cause it resolves before it has connected. Connect is async...

Comment: Oh, got it. When `try/catch` runs there is no error but because of the async nature of the `connect` an error is thrown later.

Comment: Can you please help me understand that flow or refer me to some doc?

Comment: @CodeYogi: The flow is: You create a connection object and call its `connect` method, which *starts* the process of connecting but handles it asynchronously. *Later*, asynchronously, it calls the callback you give it, passing either an error or `null` as the first argument. You look at that (`err` in the above) to determine wehether to resolve or reject your promise. More about the flow of connection, etc., in [the mysql package documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#establishing-connections).